# Боковое меню на всю высоту страницы

Tags: html, css

Ребят, либо я очень туплю, либо это нельзя сделать? Помогите, пожалуйста.

Есть хидер и футер (абсолютно позиционированный и прижатый к низу страницы). Так же есть боковое меню, которое должно растягиваться на всю допустимую высоту. Как это сделать?

http://jsfiddle.net/v9tj3/5/

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="logo"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="rBlock">
            <div class="lBlock">
                пункт <br />
                пункт <br />
                пункт <br />
                пункт <br />
                пункт <br />
                пункт <br />
                пункт <br />
                пункт <br />
                пункт <br />
                пункт <br />
                пункт <br />
                пункт <br />
                пункт <br />
                пункт <br />
                пунктend    
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li>111111</li>
                <li>222222</li>
                <li>3333</li>
                <li>4444444444</li>
                <li>5555555</li>
                <li>ABCD</li>
            </ul>

        </div>
        <div class="footer-helper"></div>
        <div class="footer">
        <span class="left">LEFT</span>
        <span class="right">RIGHT</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

-

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}
ul {
    //display: inline;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    zoom: 1;
}
li {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    height: 22px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
.container {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.header {
    background: #d1d4d9;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #a9a9a9;
    height: 108px;
    z-index: 5;
}
.logo {
    background: #000;
    float: right;
    height: 91px;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 0px;
    width: 206px;
}
.footer {
    background: #9e2627;
    border-top: 3px solid #000;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.footer-helper {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
}
.lBlock {
    background: #27919e;
    box-shadow: 2px 0px 10px #cecdd2;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: -5;
}
.rBlock {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.left {
    float: left;
}
.right {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: @chelovechki, А блок для контента страницы у вас будет? Если искать решение для вашего примера, то можно просчитаться, если вы будете дополнять разметку.

Comment: Да, будет. Справа от меню.

Comment: вот http://jsfiddle.net/v9tj3/5/ как сделать сайд высотой до футера?

Comment: а как на счет посредством js расчитать высоту моника/экрана?

Comment: без использования js к сожалению

Comment: Да ну, бросьте. Это не та задача, которая требует js. Тут можно даже без css обойтись :D

Comment: если бы можно было, то давно бы решил проблему))

Comment: можно и на паскале написать достаточно много чего)

как по мне  height: 100% - решение

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v9tj3/5/ если вы поставить здесь height:100% в нужное место, это будет работать и вы покажете это мне, то я буду очень вам благодарен) просто сидим в 2 головы думаем и ничего не приходит на ум

Comment: ну вот пожалуйста

.lSide {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 yellow;
    height: 100%;
    width: 300px;
}

все пашет красиво

Comment: на той ссылке что я вам кинул нет lside уже) за место нее есть lscroll. при вставке ваших стилей не работает)

Comment: Скажите, а для чего вам нужна высота в 100% ? Растянуть фон до самого низа?

Answer (score 1):

Вот первый результат по 2 колонкам одинаковой высоты css

http://htmlbook.ru/blog/4-metoda-sozdaniya-kolonok-odinakovoy-vysoty

- еще можно display: table

Answer (score 0):

Нужно задать для колонки свойство - 
**height: 100%;**. Странно что вы указали колонке абсолютную высоту в 200px и надеетесь, что она растянется на всю страницу. Если возникнут проблемы - обращайтесь в комментарии

Comment: 200px ширина колонки)

Comment: и если задать колонке 100% ничего не изменится)

Comment: Да ладно? lSide - это колонка? height: 200px; там указано.. или у меня галлюцинации)

Comment: в комментариях уже лежит обновленная ссылка. а в главном посте высота была указана для того чтобы показать блок. вот ссылка http://jsfiddle.net/v9tj3/5/

Comment: В колонке в данный момент что-то содержится или просто чистая разметка?

Comment: Не понял вопроса. В не зависимости от того, сколько контента будет в колонке, она должна тянутся до футера.